# How to lookup string in text file and output specific lines above and below

Tags: python, search, printing

I was not able to find a solution for my specific issue so I'm creating a new question. How can I find a string in a file and have it output from 3 lines above and 25 lines below? I have the below so far but can only print 25 below the match.

```
with open("driveDetails.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "Failed" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+25]: print l,
        print
        break
```

Below is an example of the file contents. I need to search for 'Failed' and then print from 3 lines up (ID : 0:1:6) then + 25. I didn't list all the lines for each record so I just put ...

```
ID                              : 0:1:1
Status                          : Non-Critical
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:6
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : Yes
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Product ID                      : HDSG02032923
Serial No.                      : 7DK30358
...

ID                              : 0:1:6
Status                          : Non-Critical
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:6
State                           : Failed
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : Yes
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Product ID                      : HDSG09393329
Serial No.                      : 7DK3035B
...
```

Comment: I'm aware there is a similar question but it involves omitting another matching result etc.

Comment: You know what `[i: i + 25]` is doing. Any guess what `[i - 3: i]` will do? :)

Comment: `searchlines[i - 3: i + 25]`?

Comment: Thanks, DeepSpace. I tried using i -3 but couldn't find how to implement without errors. Thanks for taking it easy on this newb.

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace and Juanpa.arrivillaga. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: lookup string in text file and output specific lines

Solution **without** bother with `indices` using **fixed** number of lines and a `dict` object.

> **Drawback**: You are loosing the order ot the lines! If this is importand, use `OrderedDict` instead.

- Open the file and loop over the lines

  ```
  with io.StringIO(DATA) as data_in:
      while True:
  ```
- Define a `dict` and read **one record** with **n** lines.

  ```
          record = {}
          for _ in range(20):
              try:
                  line = next(data_in).rstrip()
              except StopIteration:
                  break
  ```
- Get the `key`, `value` pair of every line and assign it to the `dict`.

  ```
              key, value = line.split(' : ')
              record.setdefault(key.strip(' '), value.strip(' '))
  ```
- Verify the resulting `record`.
  If key `'State' == 'Failed'` do with this `record` what ever you want.

  ```
          if not record:
              break
          elif 'State' in record:
              if record['State'] == 'Failed':
                  print('{}'.format(record))
          else:
              print('ERROR:{}'.format(record))
  ```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> {'Serial No.': '7DK3035B', 'State': 'Failed', 'ID': '0:1:6', ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***